# Laravel Paginator::make not constructing correctly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm creating a paginator with the following code:

```
    $postsPerPage = 10;

    $posts = Post::where('published', '=', true)->get()->toArray();

    $totalItems = count($posts);

    $posts = Helpers::transform_posts($posts);

    $posts = Paginator::make($posts, $totalItems , $postsPerPage);

    return $posts;
```

But it's constructing it incorrectly. 12 items (the total number of posts) are returned in the "data" array.

```
{
    "total": 12,
    "per_page": 10,
    "current_page": 1,
    "last_page": 2,
    "from": 1,
    "to": 10,
    "data": [
        // lists 12 items
    ]
}
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

For completeness' sake, here's the transform_posts() function:

```
public static function transform_posts(array $posts)
{
    foreach ($posts as &$array) {
        $array = Helpers::transform_post($array);
    }
    return $posts;
}

public static function transform_post(array $post)
{
    $publishedDate = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($post['published_date']))->diffForHumans();

    return [
        'id' => $post['id'],
        'title' => $post['title'],
        'slug' => $post['slug'],
        'subtitle' => $post['subtitle'],
        'body' => $post['body'],
        'published' => (bool)$post['published'],
        'published_date' => $post['published_date'],
        'published_date_for_humans' => $publishedDate
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're paginating manually, you have to slice your `$posts` array yourself.